# How to print data in empty array

Tags: ios, arrays, uiviewcontroller, swift4, xcode9

I'm trying to print the `chat` array that is declared as a empty global variable in a table. The data that I'm trying to print is received using web sockets. I'm assigning the data in the `messageReceived` function, and I know that the data is getting to the program because I'm printing in a label, but the moment that I'm trying to print it in the table is simple not working. All of this is in the `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Starscream

var messagetext: String = ""

var tabletext: String = ""

var chat = [String] ()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

var socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:1337/")!, protocols: ["chat"])

@IBOutlet weak var chatMessage: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
    messagetext = textField.text!
    sendMessage(messagetext)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textField.delegate = self
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return (true)
}

deinit{
    socket.disconnect(forceTimeout: 0)
    socket.delegate = nil
}
}


// MARK: - FilePrivate
fileprivate extension ViewController {

func sendMessage(_ messager: String) {

    socket.write(string: messager)
}

func messageReceived(_ message: String) {

    chatMessage.text = message
    chat.append(message)
}
}

// MARK: - WebSocketDelegate
extension ViewController : WebSocketDelegate {
public func websocketDidConnect(_ socket: Starscream.WebSocket) {

}

public func websocketDidDisconnect(_ socket: Starscream.WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "websocketDisconnected", sender: self)
}

public func websocketDidReceiveMessage(_ socket: Starscream.WebSocket, text: String) {
    // 1
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf16),
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data),
        let jsonDict = jsonData as? [String: Any],
        let messageType = jsonDict["type"] as? String else {
            return
    }

    // 2
    if messageType == "message",
        let messageData = jsonDict["data"] as? [String: Any],

        let messageText = messageData["text"] as? String {

        messageReceived(messageText)


    }
}

public func websocketDidReceiveData(_ socket: Starscream.WebSocket, data: Data) {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return(chat.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = chat[indexPath.row] as! String

    return(cell)
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are sure about there is data to be received by your view controller, The issue would be: the tableview data source methods are called *before* receiving any data, which means `chat` data source array is still empty, thus there is no data to display.

The solution for your case is to make sure to reload the tableview *after* receiving data (updating the value of `chat` data source array), which means in your case after appending a message to `chat` in `messageReceived` method by calling [*reloadData()*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) UITableView instance method:

```
func messageReceived(_ message: String) {

    chatMessage.text = message
    chat.append(message)

    // here we go:
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your message received handler, issue a tableview.reloadData()

Cheers!

Comment: Or preferably, call `insertRows` to just add the new row; reloading the whole tableview is excessive

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the tableview that there is new data.  You also need to allow for the fact that the network operation probably occurred on a background queue and UI updates must be on the main queue:

```
func messageReceived(_ message: String) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let newRow = IndexPath(row: chat.count, section:0)
        chatMessage.text = message
        chat.append(message)
        tableView.insertRows(at:[newRow],with: .automatic)
    }
}
```